# Is it possible to automatically open chrome full screen?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os

I want to set a homepage to a specific URL, and have it fullscreen, without requiring any help from the user.

Is this possible? I know i can set the default homepage to this specific URL, so thats easy. But automatically full screen?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, but here are some alternatives. They might or might not work depending on your ultimate goal.

- If you are launching the browser, start it with the `--start-maximized` flag.
- If you control the web page at that URL, you can use the [fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).